# How to send a post login request to another website in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, authentication, web

I'm trying to create a simple HTML form that i can put on my website so that people can log on and get redirected to the clients website. On my site i will have them enter a username and password and have a submit button that redirects and sends a POST request to the clients website. On the client side i have it so it will accept login request from another URL using a set or API parameters. I'll have access to the client server which is set to allow remote logins and post requests. I'm not trying to authenticate anything on my site, rather pass along the information (Username and password) to the clients website which then handles the authentication procedure. I know this can be done in PHP using cURL, however can this be adapted to html?

I'm using this site as a template: http://help.wildapricot.com/display/DOC/Adding+Wild+Apricot+login+boxes+to+another+site

Here is the form i created so far, however it wont pass on the information to

```
      <body> 
    <form action="https://millersconnect.com/thm47Login.aspx" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="browserData" id="idLoginBoxBrowserField">
            <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWGQL+raDpAgLguZKfAgLr++n9DwKUzPX1DAK2i8LfBgLclqXzAQKl6L+jAgLDoMy0DQKLqqu2BALtn7TtDwKPluWqAQLWqNHsDAKDlMOzBwKRitiMAgKsgaKzCQLs29OQBQKIoqHFCQKshq9RAv6r7bcJAqzLmpAOAt+x8L8EArHvuaYEAvmz94EPAoKC7f8IApf20owD/GWP9SCgTuHI2WDxb1YRMcOSIi4=" />
            <input type="hidden" name="__COMPRESSEDVIEWSTATE" id="__COMPRESSEDVIEWSTATE" value="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" />
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />
            <label> Username: </label>
             <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thm47Login1$UsernameTextBox" type="text" maxlength="80" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thm47Login1_UsernameTextBox" AutoComplete="off" style="width:200px;" />
            <br></br>
            <label> Password: </label>
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thm47Login1$PasswordTextBox" type="password" maxlength="128" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thm47Login1_PasswordTextBox" AutoComplete="off" style="width:200px;" />
            <br></br>
           <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox"> 
            <label for="idLoginBoxRememberMeCheckbox">Remember me</label> -->
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thm47Login1$LoginImageButton" value="LogIn" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thm47Login1_LoginImageButton" class="LoginButton" />

        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what the point of your page is. Also, how exactly does it not "pass on the information"? Note that many systems don't like that you just submit authentication data to them without having loaded the page with the authentication form on it (where they setup session cookies and the like).

Comment: The point of the page is simply to provide log in fields for a client website that the client can use on their other websites. This is the site im using to help accomplish this task, http://help.wildapricot.com/display/DOC/Adding+Wild+Apricot+login+boxes+to+another+site However, i cannot get their method to work.

Answer (score 0):

After a simple investigation of the "remote page" I see that you try to send wrong kind of informations from your form.

On destination site the user name for example is expected on this `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thm47Login1$UsernameTextBox` varialble, when you using the `username` variable. Simpilar and with the rest post variables, so there is no way to work that.

Also on aspx page there is the `Viewstate`, and the `Event Validation` variables that also must be send so the page can be valid and accept the input. This two are not exist on your "simple html" form

So to make it work, and pass all the asp.net security messures, you need to send all fields that login page expect the correct way.

Comment: Thanks, That's getting there. I see what you mean, the values being passed on obviously have to match. I have edited my code (above) to correlate to your suggestion. Now the username gets passed, but the password does not and the form does not auto submit upon arrival.